# Exception on loading main window XamlParseException on startup

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

getting and Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll additional information 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Wpf.Controller' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.'

Where Wpf.Controller is just a controller class.... so, I've re-targeted a WPF app as a dll, and have some environmental WPF applications using that XAML dll as the core UI. (minor changes to wpf.exe to help deployment).

This error isn't happening will all the wpf.exe projects... (3 of the 5 are running without issue - the code is the same, outside some app.config and properties which have deployment differences.

Comment: The exception tells you exactly where the error is, put a breakpoint there and see what happens.

Comment: H.B - how do I do that - it's in the XAML. Exceptions in XAML are a black box to me?

Comment: It explicitly says `The invocation of the constructor [...] threw an exception`, it's not XAML, it's just caused by the XAML parser.

Comment: I put an breakpoint in the start of Wpf.Controller, but it never got there - to be fair, once I'd written this up, I realized what this problem was (the old talk to the dog out loud re the issue, and 'bling', there is the answer)

Comment: Place the breakpoint in the constructor of `Wpf.Controller`, not the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

When I re-targeted the WPF.exe to a wpf.dll, I didn't change it's name, so the wpf.dll and wpf.exe project clashed. Once I renamed the dll to something else, it all worked. Error made sense, but a gotcha.